# GHCI Haskell not remembering bindings in command line

Tags: haskell, command-line, binding, ghc

I am trying to learn Haskell but it is a little hard as non of my bindings are remembered from the command line; output from my terminal below.

```
> let b = []
> b
[]
> 1:b
[1]
> b
[]
```

I have no idea why this is like this can anyone please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did you expect your example to do?  From what you've presented, I don't see anything surprising.

---

Of course, that answer is probably surprising to you, or you wouldn't have asked.  And I'll be honest: I *can* guess what you were expecting.  If I'm right, you thought the output would be:

```
> let b = []
> b
[]
> 1:b
[1]
> b
[1]
```

Am I right?  Supposing I am, then the question is: why isn't it?

Well, the short version is "that's not what `(:)` does".  Instead, `(:)` creates a new list out of its arguments; `x:xs` is a new list whose first element is `x` and the rest of which is identical to `xs`.  But it creates a *new* list.  It's just like how `+` creates a new number that's the sum of its arguments: is the behavior

```
> let b = 0
> b
0
> 1+b
1
> b
0
```

surprising, too?  (Hopefully not!)

---

Of course, this opens up the next question of "well, how do I update `b`, then?".  And this is where Haskell shows its true colors: *you don't*.  In Haskell, once a variable is bound to a value, that value will never change; it's as though all variables and all data types are `const` (in C-like languages or the latest Javascript standard) or `val` (in Scala).

*This* feature of Haskell – it's called being *purely functional* – is possibly the single biggest difference between Haskell and every single mainstream language out there.  You have to think about writing programs in a very different way when you aren't working with mutable state everywhere.

For example, to go a bit further afield, it's quite possible the next thing you'll try will be something like this:

```
> let b = []
> b
[]
> let b = 1 : b
```

In that case, what do you think is going to be printed out when you type `b`?

Well, remember, variables don't change!  So the answer is:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,…
```

forever – or until you hit control-C and abort.

This is because `let b = 1 : b` defines a *new* variable named `b`; you might as well have written `let c = 1 : c`.  Thus, you're saying "`b` is a list which is `1` followed by `b`"; since we know what `b` is, we can substitute and get "`b` is a list which is `1` followed by `1` followed by `b`", and so on forever.  Or: `b = 1 : b`, so substituting in for `b` we get `b = 1 : 1 : b`, and substituting in we get `b = 1 : 1 : 1 : 1 : …`.

(The fact that Haskell produces an infinite list, rather than going into an infinite loop, is because Haskell is *non-strict*, more popularly referred to as *lazy* – this is *also* possibly the single biggest difference between Haskell and every single mainstream language out there.  For further information, search for "lazy evaluation" on Google or Stack Overflow.)

---

So, in the end, I hope you can see why I wasn't surprised: Haskell can't possibly update variable bindings.  So since your definition was `let b = []`, then of course the final result was still `[]` :-)

Comment: This was really helpful and I thank you alot. It is hard starting out and people like me really appreciate back to basics stuff like this, I did try and research the answer but docs are hard to follow when you don't really understand anything at all.