# Haskell, list will not save variables?

Tags: list, haskell

i got a small problem, i am very new to Haskell and i dont understand why the list is empty after appending 20.

```
*Main> list
[]
*Main> add_element
[20]
*Main> list
[]
*Main>
```

my code:

```
list = []

add_element = list++[20]
```

Comment: In Haskell, everything is immutable. `add_element` returns a _new_ list with `20` at the end. It does not, and can not, modify `list`.

Comment: See also my answer to [GHCI Haskell not remembering bindings in command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35304656/237428).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell variables are immutable.  In your case:

```
list = []
```

You have defined an empty list.

```
add_element = list ++ [20]
```

The `add_element` symbol is not a function that mutates `list`.  It is actually a new list built by combining the empty list (`list`) with the singleton list `[20]`.

The top level definition `list` will never be anything besides `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Values in Haskell are immutable. Your code simply defines an empty list value for `list` that *will never change*.

`add_element` is a value representing `list` with the integer value 20 appended onto the end. It did not, it *cannot* change the `list` value.

Take a look at some [intro Haskell guides](http://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction) to get a feel for what immutability means.

Comment: I would argue a function is a value with an arrow type `a -> b`.  By that definition, `add_element` is not a function.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the tutorial!

Comment: There's no such thing as “a function with arity zero” in Haskell, and “value” and “function” are not mutually exclusive: lambdas *are* values, for instance.  See also: [“Everything is a function” in Haskell?](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) (spoiler: no).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about values vs functions! I've updated my answer

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: perhaps it would be more accurate to say that Haskell _has no such concept_ as arity. It just has values, and some of them can accept an argument to yield another value... those are functions.